# Magento 1.4.2 : errors when saving custom customer Attributes

Tags: magento

I can't save my custom customer attributes:

My Magento backend is blocked and I get this errors :

```
2011-08-03T12:27:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage\Customer\Model\Attribute\Data\.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test142_3\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93

2011-08-03T12:27:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Mage\Customer\Model\Attribute\Data\.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test142_3\app\code\local;C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test142_3\app\code\community;C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test142_3\app\code\core;C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test142_3\lib;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_test142_3\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93
```

This is my module code: 
in file mysql4-install-0.1.0.php:

```
<?php
$installer=new  Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup ('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'kd_nr', array(
    'label'        => 'Kundennummer',
    'visible'      => true,
    'required'     => false,
    'position'     => 20,
   ));   
Mage::getSingleton( 'eav/config' )
->getAttribute( 'customer', 'kd_nr' )
->setData( 'used_in_forms', array( 'adminhtml_customer' ) )
->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

and here is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Newattcustomer>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Mycompany_Newattcustomer>
    </modules>
    <global>


                <resources>
                    <newattcustomer_setup>
                        <setup>
                            <module>Mycompany_Newattcustomer</module>
                        </setup>
                        <connection>
                            <use>core_setup</use>
                        </connection>
                    </newattcustomer_setup>
                </resources>
         <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                        <kd_nr><create>1</create><update>1</update></kd_nr> 
            </customer_account>                
         </fieldsets>        

    </global>
</config>
```

I use Magento 1.4.2

Please help to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot.

[edit]

Thanks a lot for help, the code of Nasaralla seems to be working, but I discover that my problem come from a YES/NO select: Here is the code for the select box:

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'in_search', array(
    'label'        => 'Appear in search',
    'type'         => 'int',
    'input'        => 'select',
    'source'       => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'visible'      => true,
    'required'     => false,
   ));   
Mage::getSingleton( 'eav/config' )
->getAttribute( 'customer', 'in_search' )
->setData( 'used_in_forms', array( 'adminhtml_customer' ) )
->save();
```

It will be very helpful if anyone help me to solve the really problem

[/edit]

Comment: It looks like you have some deeper problem here.  Pay attention to the class file it is trying to load.  The filename is ".php" if you notice.  Without some more diagnostic info, it's a bit hard to pin down the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks Lee Saferite , I want finally to Add custom customer attributes in Magento 1.4.2. That's my final purpose, Thanks for help.

Comment: I dont think you can do    Mage::getSingleton( 'eav/config' ) ... in an upgrade or install script? if you need to set or update column do it using a script.

Comment: can you go to you db table : eav_attribute and search your attribute by attribute code and see if frontend_input is set as select and the label and model are correctly stated. Also if the cache was cleared.

Comment: Yes, my attribute have a select in frontend_input field and 
eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean as a model, and entity_type_id  = 1 (for customer) ! The cache is of course desactivated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of this part in install script

```
Mage::getSingleton( 'eav/config' )
->getAttribute( 'customer', 'kd_nr' )
->setData( 'used_in_forms', array( 'adminhtml_customer' ) )
->save();
```

In order to call eav_setup you do

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
```

and then you can updateAttribute like:

```
$setup->updateAttribute ($entityTypeId,$id,$field,$value = null,$sortOrder=null)
```

You can get the list of methods you can call in here:

[Freegento-Eav-Model-entity-setup](http://freegento.com/doc/d6/db1/class_mage___eav___model___entity___setup.html)

Therefore your code, I think, will be replaced by:

```
$setup->updateAttribute('customer', 'kd_nr', 'used_in_forms', 'adminhtml_customer');
```

Comment: I have installed this new script in a new Magento installation and it don't show my attribute in backend !

Comment: It seems like it needs to be $setup->updateAttribute('customer', 'kd_nr', 'used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer')); and I use 'is_visible' => true rather than 'visible' => true;

Comment: try playing with 'backend_model','backend_type', and 'backend_table'... in the newer version of magento you would I guess need one of these to actually tell if the attribute should be visible in the backend.

Comment: Ok this seems to work for me, Set 'frontend_input' as 'text' and set label like 'frontend_label' as of yours 'Kundennummer'... it is misleading as it has a frontend prefix... but worked for me. And if that doesn't works then add 'eav/entity_attribute_frontend_text' as your frontend_model

Comment: Always don't work for me :(  can you please copy and paste all the content of the file "mysql4-install-0.1.0.php" ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you sure your install scripts are running at all? how do you know? you need to try upgrade script or delete the line with your module id in core_resources in db tables.

Comment: yes, I upgrade the version in my xml after each modification...
And then I verify that I have the last version in the table "core_resource"

Comment: Did you clear your cache after running your script? (If its enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Ok if the above didn't work at all ... I think lets revert back to your original script and I think I can spot some fixes:

```
    <?php
$installer=new  Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup ('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'kd_nr', array(
    'label'           => 'Kundennummer',
    'is_visible'      => 1,
    'is_required'     => 0,
    'sort_order'      => 20,
   ));   

    $attr = Mage::getSingleton( 'eav/config' )->getAttribute( 'customer', 'kd_nr' );
$attr->setData( 'used_in_forms', array( 'adminhtml_customer' ) )
$attr->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

For details check the upgrade script mysql4-data-upgrade-1.4.0.0.7-1.4.0.0.8.php at core/Mage/Customer

Comment: Please have a look at my [ edit ] section in the original post

Comment: I am not sure how if these work the above didn't work, may be some silly error in code I guess?

Comment: I don't know exactly where is the problem, but it's with the boolean yes/no list box, I have written the code in my question [ edit ]. Thanks.